# Non-existence of supremum norm bound in terms of $L^2$ norm of gradient

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Show there does not exist any constant $C>0$ such that, for any $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$, the inequality
$$\lVert\phi\rVert_\infty\leq C\lVert\nabla\phi\rVert_2$$
holds.

Obviously, we can scale to take $\lVert\phi\rVert_\infty=1$. I am thus trying to construct a sequence $\phi_n$ which reaches $1$ at $0$ but for which the $L^2$ norm of the gradient becomes arbitrarily small. Surely some type of bump function will work, but I can't seem to find an explicit form. Or is there a slicker way to approach this question?

(Why just $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not $\mathbb{R}^n$? One can prove that any inequality of the form $\lVert\phi\rVert_q\leq C\lVert\nabla\phi\rVert_p$ for $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ must satisfy $q^{-1}=p^{-1}-n^{-1}$)

Comment: Why not consider constant functions as counter-examples? The gradients are zero but the max function value is nonzero.

Comment: @Michael $C^\infty_c$ means smooth and compactly supported

Comment: I guess the function $\phi\cdot(\log|x|)^{1/3}$ might work, where $\phi$ is smooth and equal to one around the origin. It is not smooth, but you can mollify it.

Comment: It is $\mathbb R^2$ to prevent you from using the scaling argument, which quickly and easily disproves that inequality on $\mathbb R^d$ with $d\ne 2$.